# js only execute at a certain time?

Tags: javascript, html

i write this code to make a basic game. The full html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The dodge game</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="play-ground">
        <div id="character"></div>
        <div id="chaser"></div>
        </div>
        <button id="control-up" class="button">UP</button>
        <button id="control-down" class="button">DOWN</button>
        <button id="control-right" class="button">RIGHT</button>
        <button id="control-left" class="button">LEFT</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

the script :

```
$(document).ready (
    function() {
        var characterPositionLeft = 0;
        var characterPositionTop = 0;
        var chaserPositionLeft = 810;
        var chaserPositionTop = 630;
        var speed = 30;
        var dspeed = 60;
        var apoint = 5;
        var testPositionLeft = function() {
            if (chaserPositionLeft > characterPositionLeft) {
                chaserPositionLeft -= 30;
                var caLeft = chaserPositionLeft + 'px';
                $('#chaser').css('margin-left', caLeft);
                leftRight();
                topBottom();
                testEndGame();
                console.log(chaserPositionLeft);
            } else if (chaserPositionLeft < characterPositionLeft) {
                chaserPositionLeft += 30;
                var caLeft = chaserPositionLeft + 'px';
                $('#chaser').css('margin-left', caLeft);
                leftRight();
                topBottom();
                testEndGame();
                console.log(characterPositionLeft);
            }
        }
        var testPositionTop = function() {
            if (chaserPositionTop > characterPositionTop) {
                chaserPositionTop -= 30;
                var caTop = chaserPositionTop + 'px';
                $('#chaser').css('margin-top', caTop);
                leftRight();
                topBottom();
                testEndGame();
                console.log(chaserPositionTop);
            } else if (chaserPositionTop < characterPositionTop) {
                chaserPositionTop += 30;
                var caTop = chaserPositionTop + 'px';
                $('#chaser').css('margin-top', caTop);
                leftRight();
                topBottom();
                testEndGame();
                console.log(chaserPositionTop);
            }
        }
        // left and right
        var CacLeftPlus = chaserPositionLeft + 30;
        var CacLeftMinus = chaserPositionLeft - 30;
        var LeftCaught = false;
        // top and bottom
        var CacTopPlus = chaserPositionTop + 30;
        var CacTopMinus = chaserPositionTop - 30;
        var TopCaught = false;
        // up
        $('#control-up').click ( 
            function() {
                testPositionTop();
                if(characterPositionTop > 0) { 
                characterPositionTop -= speed;
                var cTop = characterPositionTop + 'px';
                console.log(characterPositionTop);
                $('#character').css('margin-top', cTop);
                leftRight();
                topBottom();
                testEndGame();
                } else {
                    console.log('warning: [reached sky limit]');
                }
            }
        )
        // down
        $('#control-down').click ( 
            function() {
                testPositionTop();
                if(characterPositionTop < 630) { 
                characterPositionTop += speed;
                var cTop = characterPositionTop + 'px';
                console.log(characterPositionTop);
                $('#character').css('margin-top', cTop);
                leftRight();
                topBottom();
                testEndGame();
                } else {
                    console.log('warning: [reached earth limit]');
                }
            }
        )
        // right 
        $('#control-right').click ( 
            function() {
                testPositionLeft();
                if(characterPositionLeft < 810) { 
                characterPositionLeft += speed;
                var cTop = characterPositionLeft + 'px';
                console.log(characterPositionLeft);
                $('#character').css('margin-left', cTop);
                leftRight();
                topBottom();
                testEndGame();
                } else {
                    console.log('warning: [reached right limit]');
                }
            }
        )
        // left
        $('#control-left').click ( 
            function() {
                testPositionLeft();
                if(characterPositionLeft > 0) { 
                characterPositionLeft -= speed;
                var cTop = characterPositionLeft + 'px';
                console.log(characterPositionLeft);
                $('#character').css('margin-left', cTop);
                leftRight();
                topBottom();
                testEndGame();
                } else {
                    console.log('warning: [reached left limit]');
                }
            }
        )
        var leftRight = function() {
            if(characterPositionLeft == CacLeftPlus || characterPositionLeft == CacLeftMinus) {
                LeftCaught = true;
                console.log('worked?');
            } else {

            }
        }
        var topBottom = function() {
            if(characterPositionTop == CacTopPlus || characterPositionLeft == CacTopMinus) {
                TopCaught = true;
                console.log('worked?');
            } else {

            }
        }
        var testEndGame = function () {
            if (LeftCaught == true && TopCaught == true) {
            console.log('game over');
            alert('game over');
        } else {

        }
        }
    }
)
```

Everything works fine until the functions leftRight, upBottom and testEndGame. They only console worked when the console is logged 600 and 630. Can anyone please tell me the flaw in this code and a way to fix this? Here is the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/StK7r/1/

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want

```
if(characterPositionTop == CacTopPlus || characterPositionLeft == CacTopMinus) {
```

to instead test

```
if(characterPositionTop <= CacTopPlus && characterPositionTop >= CacTopMinus) {
```

because you intend your character to be caught inside a box. Same for left. Also, you were testing your 'top' position against your 'left'.

EDIT later:

I've updated the fiddle a bit. I noticed this also:

```
     // left and right
    var CacLeftPlus = chaserPositionLeft + 30;
    var CacLeftMinus = chaserPositionLeft - 30;
    var LeftCaught = false;
    // top and bottom
    var CacTopPlus = chaserPositionTop + 30;
    var CacTopMinus = chaserPositionTop - 30;
```

You are not updating these variables when chaserPositionTop/Left changes. They are being bound by value here, so obviously they remained forever at the value you are giving them in the initializer.

Comment: +1 for understanding (I think) what the game was supposed to do, I'd only just barely understood the code :)

Comment: +1, every time i want to add some code, i have to read it all again